# Run/Install ruby gem from io.js with child_process

Tags: ruby, node.js, rubygems, jekyll, electron

**AIM:** Create a desktop app(GUI) with Electron(Atom Shell), that runs a gem's commands from io.js.

**1.** The problem is that I want to know which is the best way to handle the commands call to the gem inside the system.

**2.** If the gem is not installed inside the system the desktop app is worthless. Which is the best way to handle this dependency?

**EXAMPLE CODE THAT I'VE SORTED OUT**

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var jk = spawn('jekyll', ['serve']);

jk.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log(data.toString('utf8')); // WRITE IN THE CONSOLE GEM OUTPUT
});
```

Is that code a good way to execute the commands?.

My ideal scenario is "As a user I want to press a button that compile the site" -> On click then run the build command of the gem that will be handled by that code possibly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a contrived example using "ShellJS" and jekyll as the dependency:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');

if (shell.which('gem')) {
  if (shell.exec("gem install jekyll").code === 0) {
      shell.exec("jekyll new my-site");
      //Do more stuff
      shell.exec("jekyll build");
  }
} else {
  echo('Sorry, this program requires gem. Install from Source');
  exit(1);
}
```

The idea is to use which to check if gem is installed and then install the dependency. You can then use exec to run commands with that gem.

Comment: Probably not. Maybe using a Ruby framework that allows you to create desktop apps might be a better idea.

Comment: Uhmm OK so that's probably the only way to use a gem without a Ruby stack